# Protractor test failed only in firefox (due to retrieve the option in a select box)

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I am using protractor 3.0 with firefox 44 and chrome. My test passed when I use chrome, but some of my test (mostly the test involving select field) failed with firefox. I used this to retrieve the proper option

```
mySelect.element(by.cssContainingText('option', "Terminology")).click();
```

(I tried using this function and I had same result )

```
mySelect.all(by.css("option")).each(function(option){
            option.getText().then(function(text){
                if(text=="Terminology"){
                    option.click();
                }
            })
    });
```

Any idea about It ?

Comment: How does it fail? Please post a traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Martin, try this and see what happens?

```
mySelect.element(by.cssContainingText('option', "Terminology")).click();
browser.actions().sendKeys( protractor.Key.ENTER ).perform();
```

If it does work then the cause might be because the model isnt being updated on the click call

Comment: thanks for the answer, I will try tomorrow at work :).
I manage to do it using
mySelect.sendKeys("Terminology"). So you are probably right

Answer (score -1):

Thank you TesterPhi

You solution is working on firefox however it failed with chrome.

But at the end the

```
mySelect.sendKeys("Terminology")
```

is working with both chrome and firefox,but I think is not a very good way to do it.

Comment: Yeah I agree its not a very good way to deal with it... 

https://www.bountysource.com/issues/1603443-calling-click-on-an-option-element-inside-a-select-doesn-t-update-the-model-in-firefox-only

This is an interesting article which discusses the problem. I dont think there is of yet an ideal solution?